# Est-ce que cette phrase est correcte ? "les modifications que tu m'as demandées"

Tags: verbes

Le complément direct du verbe est bien placé devant le verbe, donc cette forme est correcte non ?

Comment: Oui, c'est parfait, ainsi que ton raisonnement. Comme on ne veut pas trop corriger [des milliards de telles phrases](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=accord+participe+pass%C3%A9), je ferme la question. Bienvenue à French Stack Exchange !

Comment: Si seulement tous les natifs pouvaient écrire comme ça...